# Gulp - create two files with gulp-ruby-sass

Tags: javascript, gulp

I need to create two css files with gulp-ruby-sass plugin - one compressed and one extended. At the moment two files are being created, but both of them are extended. Is there some way for me to do this?
Code:

```
gulp.task('style', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({
            style:'compressed'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('devCSS', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'expanded'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/dev/'));
});  
gulp.task('default', ['uglify', 'style', 'watch', 'devCSS']);
```

Comment: You mean `gulp style` doesn't minify css?

Comment: Nope. It seems that the task devCSS is messing with style task, and both files are expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp task dependencies (the passed array), runs asynchronously, so you don't know which one runs first. You have two tasks `style` and `devCSS` that operates on the same directory. They should not be executed asynchronously, that is should not be passed to the same dependency list. Seperate them:

`gulp.task('defaultDev', ['uglify', 'watch', 'devCSS']);`

`gulp.task('default', ['uglify', 'style']);`

If you need to run them in the same task use [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence).